# c# how to call an Action from generic extension method in another class

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

I am trying to write a Library of functions to be used by all the classes in my project ( a little unity game ). This question has possibly been asked already but I'm not sure what to search for and haven't found anything yet, so here I am.
I want to create a function in a Library that takes in argument a delegate ( or at least, an object of type Action, not sure if that's really called a delegate ) and runs it. The catch is, this Action has to be called by an object of another type and potentially modify it ( meaning it has to be called by the other object ). I'm thinking about using a generic extension method for this.
Here is some code I have for now( although this code doesn't work, it should be pretty explicit):

```
    public static class Library 
{
    public static void doStuffandCallMethod<T>(this T self, Action methodToExecute) {
        //DoStuff
        self.methodToExecute();

    }
    
}
```

which is my attempt at generalizing this code:

```
public static void WaitAndDo( Action methodToExecute) {
        //DoSuff();
        methodToExecute();
    }
```

which works fine.
However, the compilator doesn't understand and look for a method called methodToExecute in the class   T instead of replacing it by the method described by the parameter (Action) methodToExecute.
How am I supposed to do call this Action as the object self, from the class Lib?

Big thanks to those who take the time to thing about it ;)

Edit: Here is a minimal exemple:

```
public class myObject {
    int number;

    public myObject() {
        number = 0;
    }

    public void method1() {
        Console.WriteLine("Bob is a great guy");
    }
    public void method2() {
        number++;
    }

    public void method3() {
        DoItForMe<myObject>(method2);
    }
}

public class Lib {
    public static void DoItForMe<T>(this T self, Action methodToExecute) {
        self.methodtoExecute();
    }
}
```

Then from the main:

```
myObject bob = new myObject();
bob.method3();
Console.WriteLine("bob's number is" + bob.number);
```

should give the output

bob's number is 1

Comment: Can you show how you would want to use `doStuffandCallMethod`?

Comment: A [mcve] would make it much easier to help you here.

Comment: i added an exemple :)

Comment: As an aside, it's really helpful if examples follow the idiomatic naming conventions for the language - it's just less distracting that way.

Comment: It's not clear why this is an extension method at all... but there are just four things wrong with your example code: 1) You've got a typo: your parameter is called `methodToExecute` but you're trying to invoke it as `methodtoExecute`; 2) The extension method must be in a static class; 3) You need to invoke the extension method on "this" explicitly, e.g. `this.DoItForMe<myObject>(method2);`; 4) You should remove the `self.` part.

Comment: I'd personally just make it a non-generic method, and add `using static Lib;` - then you can just write `DoItForMe(method2);`

Comment: thanks for your helpful remarks! I'll look into it, looks like I should be able to do things with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

methodToExecute must be called without self, because this method is a parameter and not a method of self.

```cs
public static class Library
{
    public static void DoStuffandCallMethod<T>(this T self, Action methodToExecute)
    {
        //DoStuff
        methodToExecute();
    }
}
```

*DoStuffandCallMethod* is an extension method of your instance, you can call it with *this*:

```cs
public class MyObject
{
    private int number;
    public int Number => number;   // if you want to access from outside.
    // ...

    public void Method2()
    {
        number++;
    }

    public void Method3()
    {
        this.DoStuffandCallMethod(Method2);
    }
}
```

You are extending every type. You can call *DoStuffandCallMethod* from an int, ... I have the feeling that interfaces are a better approach than extension methods for your problem.